# Projecting points using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to:

1. do ray-plane intersection against several points that are in world coordinates,
2. then I get those points that are intersected
3. then I try to project these points from that world coordinates into image coordinates,

but I get points in the range 0.4, 0.1, 0.5..etc.

Here is what I'm doing, hope that you spot an error

```
      Mat cameraIntrinsics( 3, 3, CV_32F );

      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 0, 0 ) = 1.6003814935684204;
      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 0, 1 ) = 0;
      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 0, 2 ) = -0.0021958351135253906;
      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 1, 0 ) = 0;
      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 1, 1 ) = 1.6003814935684204;
      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 1, 2 ) = -0.0044271680526435375;
      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 2, 0 ) = 0;
      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 2, 1 ) = 0;
      cameraIntrinsics.at<float>( 2, 2 ) = 1;


      Mat invCameraIntrinsics = cameraIntrinsics.inv();

      std::vector<cv::Point3f> points3D;
      std::vector<Ray> rays;
      for ( int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++ )
      {
        cv::Point3f pt;

        pt.z = -1.0f;

        pt.x = corners[i].x;
        pt.y = corners[i].y;

        points3D.push_back( pt );

        Ray ray;

        ray.origin = Vec3f( 0, 0, 0);
        ray.direction = Vec3f( pt.x, pt.y, pt.z );

        rays.push_back( ray );
      }

      std::vector<cv::Point3f> pointsTransformed3D;


      cv::transform( points3D, pointsTransformed3D, invCameraIntrinsics );


      std::vector<cv::Vec3f> contacts;

      for ( int i = 0; i < pointsTransformed3D.size(); i++ )
      {
        Vec3f pt( pointsTransformed3D[i].x, pointsTransformed3D[i].y, pointsTransformed3D[i].z );

        cv::Vec3f contact;
        std::pair<bool, double> test = linePlaneIntersection( contact, rays[i].direction, rays[i].origin, Vec3f( 0, 1, 0 ), pt );
        if (test.first == true )
        {
          cv::Vec3f contact( rays[i].origin + ( rays[i].direction) * test.second);
          contacts.push_back( contact );
        }
      }


      Mat rotationMatrix( 3, 3, CV_32F );

      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 0, 0 ) = 0.9115078799790896;
      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 0, 1 ) = -0.1883612409043686;
      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 0, 2 ) = -0.3656137684237178;
      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 1, 0 ) = -0.3046835686704949;
      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 1, 1 ) = 0.2878667580409447;
      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 1, 2 ) = -0.9079100465339108;
      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 2, 0 ) = 0.2762631132059388;
      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 2, 1 ) = 0.9389636694462479;
      rotationMatrix.at<float>( 2, 2 ) = 0.2050022432604093;

      cv::Mat rVec( 3, 1, CV_32F ); // Rotation vector
      Rodrigues( rotationMatrix, rVec );
      double norm = cv::norm( rVec );

      float theta = (float)(sqrt( rVec.at<float>(0)*rVec.at<float>( 0 ) + rVec.at<float>( 1 )*rVec.at<float>( 1 ) + rVec.at<float>( 2 )*rVec.at<float>( 2 ) ) * 180 / 3.14567898726);

      cv::Mat tVec( 3, 1, CV_32F ); // Translation vector
      tVec.at<float>( 0 ) = 21.408294677734375;
      tVec.at<float>( 1 ) = 531.1319580078125;
      tVec.at<float>( 2 ) = 705.74224853515625;

      cv::Mat distCoeffs( 5, 1, CV_32F );   // Distortion vector
      distCoeffs.at<float>( 0 ) = 0;
      distCoeffs.at<float>( 1 ) = 0;
      distCoeffs.at<float>( 2 ) = 0;
      distCoeffs.at<float>( 3 ) = 0;
      distCoeffs.at<float>( 4 ) = 0;

      std::vector<cv::Point2d> projectedPoints;
      std::vector < cv::Point3d> ContactPoints;

      for ( int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++ )
      {
        cv::Point3d pt;

        pt.x = contacts[i][0];
        pt.y = contacts[i][1];
        pt.z = contacts[i][2];

        ContactPoints.push_back( pt );
      }


      cv::projectPoints( ContactPoints, rVec, tVec, cameraIntrinsics, distCoeffs, projectedPoints );

      for ( size_t i = 0; i < projectedPoints.size(); i++ )
      {
        cv::Point2d pt;

        pt.x = projectedPoints[i].x;
        pt.y = projectedPoints[i].y;

        cv::circle( src, pt, 10, cv::Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), -1 );
      }

      imshow( "My window", src );
    }
  }

cv:waitKey( 0 );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The cameraIntriniscs looks really weird... the focal length is tooo small (it normally is in the 100s even 1000s... and the  center is too small as well, normally it is lke in the image center. That would be like in a corner..... How did you obtain it?

Comment: @api55 I got it from the ARKIT

Comment: hmmm, that is weird... they look totally wrong, at least for OpenCV. maybe it is scale somehow or it uses different notation, or both. [Here](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/) you can find more info about the camera matrix. When the focal length is smaller than the real one, you will see the objects smaller.... this makes sense with the behaviour you get. Also, the optical center is 0 in your case. Try using 1600 as focal length and the middle of the image as center (e.g. if it is 640x480, it will be in 319.5, 239.5) and you probably get something that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Your intrinsic parameters are way too small: a focal length of 1.6 pixels is nonsense for a physical quasi-pinhole camera.

Comment: I'm actually following that article http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=363
If you want here is the full source code : https://pastebin.com/9MKx0uCT  and use that image https://imgur.com/a/eFzbM